# Outcome analysis after performing matching using cardmatch in R

Tags: r, cardinality, propensity-score-matching

After matching performed using this package below:

https://rdrr.io/cran/designmatch/man/cardmatch.html

Instead of simply computing the difference in means, how do I obtain a regression style output format?

After the last step in cardmatch code from link above:

```
# The mean difference in outcomes is the same...
mean(re78[t_id_1]-re78[c_id_1])
mean(re78[t_id_2]-re78[c_id_2])

# ... but their standard deviation is reduced
sd(re78[t_id_1]-re78[c_id_1])
sd(re78[t_id_2]-re78[c_id_2])
```

I am interested in something like this instead of simply getting differences in means.

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.3483     0.1007  18.681  < 2e-16 ***
treated      -7.4793     0.8387  -6.459 4.87e-10 ***
```

How do I form a dataframe from cardmatch package step and then use glm or svyglm to perform outcome analysis?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to retain the pair membership, just subset your dataset using the returned `t_id` and `c_id` components of the `cardmatch` output. For example, if the output object was called `cm` and your dataset was called `data`, running the following would create a dataset of just the matched units:

```
data_matched <- data[c(cm$t_id, cm$c_id),]
```

If you care about the pair membership and want to create a variable that represents the pair ID of each unit, you can use the following code (which assumes the row names of `data` are absent or just the numbers indexing the row):

```
pair_df <- data.frame(pair = factor(c(seq_along(cm$t_id), 
                                      seq_along(cm$c_id))), 
                      row.names = c(cm$t_id, cm$c_id))
data_matched <- merge(data, pair_df, by = 0, all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)[-1]
```

Any unmatched units will have `NA` for the new `pair` variable (or you can set `all.x = FALSE` to only retain the matched units). You can use the `pair` variable as a random effect in a mixed effect model using `glmer()` in the `lme4` package (equivalent to a paired t-test) or in cluster-robust standard errors in a standard regression model using `glm()` to account for the pairing in your analysis. You can add covariates to improve precision and reduce remaining bias.